# How to check number of gRPC requests hits?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, grpc, grpc-java

A Java gRPC server is running as a container in kubernetes, I am not able to figure out how to check the **total number of gRPC requests hits** to this server. It isn't equal to the **number of successful hits**, maybe the server is down and not able to entertain the requests, but hit count would increase anyway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can build logging into your server using [logging via interceptors](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/java-grpc-prometheus). 
This allows collection of data while your server is running, but obviously *not when it isn't*.

If you implement a [TCP liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-tcp-liveness-probe) for your service, Kubernetes can automatically take care of some sources of downtime e.g. your service needing restarted or moved to another node.

This might cut down the cases when you actually need to count failed requests.

You could use a gRPC-aware proxy that sits between your server and the cluster / outside world e.g. [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/).

This would allow you to count all requests regardless of success or failure (assuming the cluster was always running).

Comment: Hello Peter, Thanks for your reply. The main problem was to collect total number, a request being entertained can be easily logged. Is there any implementation to the gRPC-aware proxy, as I think this would be a much overhead to the system.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't use a proxy? I can't think of any other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can have kubernetes ingres monitoring and metrics set up using prometheus and Grafana. Your k8s cluster may have already setup this, check with your ops guy

More here

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/monitoring.md

Once your metric is in prometheus, you can set up custom metrics and alerts off of that data using Grafana

Comment: This will give you metrics which is related to kubernetes, i.e. all what is visible to it. But my doubt is about application running inside, the grpc server

Comment: You might know this already, in kubernetes the server/pods are ephemeral. You might be having N number of servers aka pods. And usually the individual pod's metrics is irrelevant because it doesn't convey any information, why would you need that?

Comment: Its the concept of cattle, you will have the count of your total cattle, will you be naming individual cattle? probably not